# Проблемы с обратной совместимостью AppCompat, Android ниже 5

Tags: android, actionbar, android-spinner, android-appcompat

Добра всем! Добавил в приложение App Bar по этой инструкции [Adding the App Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html)
В итоге на андроиде ниже 5 (не Lollipop устройствах) ActionBar отображается с артифактами, кроме этого такая же проблема со Spinner, тоже отображается с графическими ошибками.

[image: ActionBar и под ним закрытый Spinner]
[image: Раскрытый Spinner]
[image: Меню в ActionBar]

Что сделано:

1 - В gradle для модуля подключена библиотека

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

2 - В манифесте стоит тема для приложения

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

3 - в Layout для активити добавлены виджеты Toolbar и Spinner

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<Spinner
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/userSpinner"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

4 - В сама активите наследуется от AppCompatActivity и в onCreate там добавлены Toolbar и Spinner

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] spinnerData = {"item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

        //[START make spinner]
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.userSpinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> customAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerData);
        spinner.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        //[STOP make spinner]
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

В итоге имею такой результат как на картинках. Как побороть?

Comment: А если версию либ понизить до 23.3.0?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб попробовал. Есть разница, фон в меню и в списке стал нормальным, но все равно остались артефакты при кликах по пунктам меню и списка. Так же стрелка у списка растянута на всю ширину так и осталось. Я по пробовал все версии библиотек по ветке 23. Решения проблемы нет :(

Comment: Хм... Единственная мысль - у вас какой-то странный предок у виджетов, раз у них есть атрибуты типа `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf`

Comment: Да не, это новая фишка появилась после установки Android Studio 2.2. Это выравнивание относительно других элементов в android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout. Можно убрать. Глюк останется.

Comment: А если убрать сам ConstraintLayout? Просто у вас никаких ошибок не видно, всё как у всех, а ошибку такую я впервые за годы вижу. Тем более, на разных девайсах.

Comment: У меня изначально было в LinearLayout. Это я тестовое приложение сделал. Новая студия по умолчанию такой вот ConstraintLayout поставила.

Comment: Т.е. и с LinearLayout та же беда?..

Comment: Да LinearLayout та же беда. Не знаю в чем дело. Я удалил из SDK manager и заново поставил Android Support Repository и Google Repository. Не помогло.

Comment: Ну... Может у вас где-то кроме тега Apllication какие-то тему прописаны? Для активити, например? А если стили у Toolbar убрать? А если создать чистый проект с EmptyActivity через студию?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Для активити тем нет. У меня всего одна активити. Я специально создал новый пустой проект с EmptyActivity. У тулбара стили убрал, не помогло. Юрий а могли бы вы создать у себя такое простое приложение с ActionBar и проверить?

Comment: У меня всё работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверьте что у вас `build.gradle` модуля приложения `compileSdkVersion` не выше 23, `buildToolsVersion` не выше "23.0.2", `targetSdkVersion` не выше 23. В главной `build.gradle` версия градл плагина не выше `"com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2"`. Это последние стабильные версии. Если ставите выше можете ожидать каких угодно эффектов, в том числе и этих. Да и студию лучше бы поставить стабильную 2.1.2. Вообще если работаете с нестабильными версиями и что то происходит не так, то начинать лучше с проверки так же ли это в стабильных. Вообще на вид у вас 9-патчи почему то перестали восприниматься 9-патчами и отображаются как просто картинки. То ли система сборки как то глючит, то ли сами ресурсы откуда то битые взялись...

Comment: Благодарю. Вы меня спасли от долгих и мучительных поисков. Проблема была в  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha2'
 заменил его на classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2' и все стало отлично!