# Проблема с выделением компонентов

Tags: java, android

Полностью с нуля создал проект, и когда делаю какие-то выделения, выделяется не так как надо. Причем такая проблема только на устройствах ниже 21 апи и только новые проекты. Тоесть старые(созданные несколько месяцев назад) проекты работают нормально, а вот новые уже с такой ерундой. Начал сверять старый и новый проект, все версии библиотек совпадают. В стилях тоже почти ничего нету. Может кто сталкивался уже с таким?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

def versionMajor = 1
def versionMinor = 0
def versionPatch = 0

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

dexOptions {
    maxProcessCount 4
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.company.example"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 100 + versionPatch
    versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = false
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError true
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5'
}
```

Gradle проекта

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.0-beta4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос build.gradle. Скорее всего дело в каких-то бета-версиях чего-то. Например версии gradle. Или build-tools

Comment: да вроде бы ничего такого. добавил gradle. Ещё добавлю что использую Android Studio 2.2 Preview 3

Comment: А в файле уровня проекта какая версия самого gradle используется?

Comment: добавил gradle проекта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему [дело](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/534047/17609) в альфа-версии gradle.

Поменяйте в `build.gradle` уровня проекта версию на стабильную вместо альфы. Т.е.

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

вместо *classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'*